# Date: Date type in csv is uploaded as integer in R

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I had uploaded a csv containing a date column. When i did `read.csv(`) in R and checked the **typeof** all columns, it displays all columns as integer type. 
I was able to convert character types successfully by using :

```
as.character(mydata$col3)
```

When trying the similar for date (values as- 17-JAN-95) as:

```
as.date(mydata$col5,"%Y%M%D")
```

The values returned are: 
please suggest the correct approach for modifying the datatype.

Comment: try using "%d-%B-%y" as format

Comment: try `as.Date('17-JAN-95',"%d-%b-%y")` (or `%B` instead of `%b`, both should work)

Comment: also look into `colClasses` argument to `read.csv`

Comment: When you ask a question it is always better to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
strptime(mydata$col5, '%d-%b-%y')
```